# How to load a url in webview, phonegap for iphone is automatically loading www/index.html

Tags: xcode, cordova

I am doing an app the need to load an external url. During testing period, we're just redirect to the url using javascript.

We just add the code below on index.html:

```
function onDeviceReady()
{
        document.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

But now, we want a way to directly load the external url in the webview using objected c. I've been trying to modify the NSURLs on AppDelegate.m but it's still loading the index.html.

Answer (score 0):

u have 2 options.
either u can use the childbrowser plugin " https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser "  to load the external in a small browser inside the app. 
or u can write a plugin which loads the external url in a similar way like the index.html is loaded.

Comment: can you give me a link of a good tutorial on how to write my own plugin?

Comment: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753496/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS